# How to Dismiss/Cancel the status bar notification in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created a status bar notification in android programmatically using the code given below with a particular id

```
    Notification notification;
    public static NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

private static void createStatusBarNotification(Context context,CharSequence NotificationTicket, CharSequence NotificationTitle,CharSequence NotificationContent, int icon) {
            myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            notification = new Notification(icon, NotificationTicket, when);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, NotificationTitle,NotificationContent, contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            myNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        }
```

Now what i want is remove this notification on clicking of a button in tha application programatically.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use this :

```
public void clearNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

To cancel all

`myNotificationManager.cancelAll();`

Comment: This is what i wanted :)

Answer (score 8):

Use the same ID as used while notifying

```
 myNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID)
```